# Running Sum From Coredata Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to get a running sum of all transactions in Coredata that are less than or equal to the date being evaluated.  I can get the total of all transactions in the given day, but I haven't figured out how to get the running sum of the transactions up to and including the evaluated date.  Here is my code:

```
var _fetchedData: [[String : AnyObject]]? = nil
var fetchedData:[[String : AnyObject]]? {


    if _fetchedData != nil {
        return _fetchedData
    }

    print("====== fetchedData Initialization ======")

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Transaction", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity


    // Pull sum of transactions
    let expression=NSExpressionDescription()
    expression.expression=NSExpression(format: "sum:(splits.amount)")
    expression.name="Sum"
    expression.expressionResultType=NSAttributeType.DoubleAttributeType



    // Pull running sum of transactions
    let subqueryExpression=NSExpressionDescription()
    let sqExpression=NSExpression(format: "SUBQUERY(splits, $t, date<$t.date)")
    subqueryExpression.expression=NSExpression(forFunction: "sum", arguments: [sqExpression])
    subqueryExpression.expressionResultType=NSAttributeType.DoubleAttributeType
    subqueryExpression.name="RunningSum"

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 200

    // Sets up query details
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch=["date",expression]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy=["date"]
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType


    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    var results:[[String : AnyObject]]=[]

    do {
        results = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        print("results=\(results)")
        for result in results {


            var filteredResults:[[String:AnyObject]] = results.filter({
                ($0["date"] as! NSDate).compare(result["date"] as! NSDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending

            })

            //                let runningTotal=filteredResults.reduce(0) { ($0["Sum"] as! NSNumber) + ($1["Sum"] as! NSNumber)}
            print("runningTotal=\(filteredResults) result=\(result)")

        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error=\(error)")
    } catch {
        print("catch")
    }

    _fetchedData=results

    return _fetchedData

}
```

The running sum expression does not compile and I get an error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'sum is not a supported
>   method.'

Can anyone help me figure out how to calculate the running sum for the evaluated date in the fetch request?

Comment: Did you try `NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", …` with a colon?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  It compiles when I do it that way, but it crashes when I add it to the `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch=["date",expression, subqueryExpression]`.  Error code is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Bad argument to aggregate total in select (must be a keypath or constant value) : (
    "SUBQUERY(splits, $t, date < $t.date)"
)'"

Comment: Shouldn't the amount key be somewhere in the expression for the running sum?

Comment: Probably, and I have tried several variations with `splits.amount` in the expression but those did not work either.  I think I am going to try another approach and just run the fetch for each date individually.  That is probably less efficient, but I don't know how else to do it at this point.